# Inject vue js code to a DIV tag

Tags: dynamic, vue.js, code-injection

I created a component,

```
var component = {
         template : "<div>\
                         Case 1: <div v-html='vHtml'></div>\
                         Case 2: <div>Count is <span @click='doClick'>{{count}}</span></div>\
                     </div>",
         data :function(){
                return {
                      vHtml:"",
                      count:0
                }
         },
         mounted : function(){
                  this.vHtml = 'Count is <span @click="doClick">{{count}}</span>';
         },
        methods:{
            doClick:function(){
               console.log("Cliked");
            }
        }
}
```

The case 2 works as expected. I want to have the same behavior dynamically (like 
 case 1).

I can append value of `count` variable by using

`this.vHtml = 'Count is <span @click="doClick">'+this.count+'</span>`

but how can i trigger method `doClick` when the `span` is clicked?

How can I inject vue js code to a component DIV tag dynamically?

Comment: why do you need to manipulate html directly? just use `v-if` for example.

Comment: @MaxSinev thank you so much. v-if can be used. Is there any way i can inject vue code dynamically ?

Comment: what does it mean?